# Взаимодействие классов из двух файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, python-3.6, импорт

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Есть веб-сервер Flask, который работает с файлом `api.py`.
Этот файл должен импортировать два класса: `class_a` и `class_b` из файлов `classes/a.py` и `classes/b.py`, а далее работать с ними.

На данный момент оба эти класса находятся в файле `api.py`:

```
class class_a:
    def do_sth(self, x): return x + 5
class class_b:
    def start(self): return a.do_sth(5)

a = class_a()
b = class_b()
print(b.start())
```

Так всё отлично работает, но стоит попробовать такой вариант, где в коде файла api.py прописано это:

```
from classes.a import class_a
from classes.b import class_b

a = class_a()
b = class_b()

print(b.start())
```

В файле `classes/a.py` прописано это:

```
class class_a:
    def do_sth(self, x): return x + 5
```

А в файле `classes/b.py`, соответственно, это:

```
class class_b:
    def start(self): return a.do_sth(5)
```

Запуск файла `api.py` выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

Понятно, что проблема в том, что класс `class_b` находится в другом пространстве имён, но

- Почему тогда 1 вариант работал отлично?
- Почему добавление строки `global a` перед `a = class_a()` в файле `api.py` не помогает?

Пробовал добавить пустой файл `__init__.py`, не помогло.

UPD:
Решением может послужить добавление строки `import __main__` в файле b.py, но, во-первых, придётся к каждому обращению к переменным api.py добавить **main**.some_variable, к тому же, я считаю, что это далеко не лучшее решение.

Answer (score 0):

У вас *b.py* не знает кто такой **a**, для этого вам нужно импортировать "модуль" **a**

```
from classes.a import class_a as a

class class_b:
   def start(self): return a.do_sth(self, 5)
```

После запуска *api.py*, результат равен 10.

Comment: Да, это работает. Но представьте что в файле api.py после инициализации класса class_a я присваиваю ему какие-то св-ва, а потом из класса class_b хочу получить это свойство. Т.е все три файла api.py, a.py, b.py должны иметь одно одинаковое пространство имён.

Comment: @Bleno какое-нибудь `a.svoystvo` будет замечательно работать, проблемы тут нет

Comment: @andreymal, прям с языка снял, хах. спасибо

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PShfNVGM. AttributeError: class_a instance has no attribute 'test'

Comment: @Bleno, а как же self.test объявить? и зачем 'x' в class_a? Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос целиком, а потом задавайте

Comment: Вот этот код отлично работает и прекрасно показывает проблему, которую я сейчас решаю. Но мы немного отошли от темы, суть в том, чтобы все три файла создали общее пространство имён. Т.е если в файлах a.py и b.py прописать строчки print(__name__), то получим classes.a и classes.b соответсвенно, а нужно чтобы было единое пространство __main__, тогда все переменные будут доступны из всех файлов. Думаю я близок к решению, но не откажусь от других вариантов.

Comment: Комметарий @andreymal и есть ответ на ваш дополнительный вопрос